# Uniform Continuity Proof

Tags: analysis, uniform-continuity

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin x^3}{x+1}$$

If $f(x)$ is defined for $x \in [0,\infty)$,  I can see that its derivative is bounded in the interval so it is just the matter of proving it. Im going for an $e-s$ proof, but I'm stumbling in terms of finding an appropriate $s.$ Also, would be nice if someone could give an explanation if possible what it means for a function to be uniformly continuous graphically - such that I can tell almost instantly if a function is uniform continuous (if possible).

Thanks.

Comment: When you wrote "$e-s$ proof" did you mean $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof? Typeset by: `$\varepsilon$-$\delta$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\epsilon > 0$. Find $k > 1$ large enough that $1/x < \epsilon/4$ whenever $x \geq k$. Now, since $f(x)$ is continuous and $[0,k+1]$ is compact, then $f$ restricted to $[0,k+1]$ is uniformly continuous. Let $\delta_1 > 0$ be small enough that if $x, y \in [0,k+1]$ then $|x-y|< \delta_1$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Now, suppose that $x \in (k+1,\infty)$ and $|x-y|<1$. In particular this implies that $k<x$ and $k<y$. Then 
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| = \left| \frac{(y+1) \sin(x^3) - (x+1)\sin(y^3)}{(x+1)(y+1)}\right| \\ \leq \left| \frac{y\sin(x+1) - x\sin(y+1)}{(x+1)(y+1)}\right| + \left|\frac{\sin(x+1)-\sin(y+1)}{(x+1)(y+1)} \right| \\ \leq \frac{2 \max(x,y)}{(x+1)(y+1)}+\frac{2}{(x+1)(y+1)} \\ < \frac{2}{\min(x,y)}+\frac{2}{(x+1)(y+1)} \\ < 2\frac{1}{k}+2\frac{1}{k} \\ < 4(\epsilon/4) = \epsilon.
$$
The very last inequality came with our choice of $k$.
So, taking $\delta = \min(\delta_1, 1)$ will do the trick!

Graphically, you might think of uniform continuity as saying that $f$ can't move vertically too steeply at any points (otherwise any small changes in the domain [controlled by $\delta$] can still result in large changes in the range [controlled by $\epsilon$]). For example, $f(x) = 1/x$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ since near $0$ it grows nearly vertically. Similarly, for any $n > 1$,  $f(x) = \pm x^n$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0, \infty)$ because as $x$ approaches $\infty$ the function $f$ moves nearly vertically (up if $+x^n$ down if $-x^n$).

Comment: THANKS! this is very helpful

Comment: No problem! To be sure, the graphically illustration is just for some intuition. It is possible for a function to head vertically "briefly" but still be uniformly continuous. For example $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,\infty)$ is vertical at $x = 0$, but doesn't travel vertically "long enough" for it to prevent $f(x)$ from uniform continuity. It does, however, prevent $f(x)$ from being Lipshitz.

Comment: You're absolutely right.. I'm sorry about that. I've given you another argument in the above solution. We won't get away with the derivative argument, unfortunately. However, we're not out of luck!

Comment: no need to say sorry. Im starting to grasp the concept of uniform continuity better from your posts, thanks again